# random background color for each array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating random color using that:

```
var rand = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
```

and I'm mapping data:

```
var mappedData = data.data.map(function(item){    

    return { value: item[1], name: item[0], color: rand };
);
```

after which it's passed to chart.

**But** it generates whole chart with one color. How can I do that this change display for each chart element?

I've tried to add `var bgColor = rand;` inside of mappedData and then assign it to `color: bgColor` but it gave me same result

Comment: you need to provide more code.  from what you're showing, you've assigned one color to rand.  where are you iterating over your array?

Comment: Try this: `var mappedData = data.data.map(function(item) {
  var rand = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
  return {value: item[1], name: item[0], color: rand};
 });`. You may not be creating `rand` for each item!

Comment: You're missing a `}` on the final line: `});`

Comment: @RayonDabre type that as answer. it solved

Comment: from what i see, your rand variable is outside of the scope und is beeing initialized only once.
You could calculate a set of random colors in advance or just put the randomizer inside the data.data.map function like this:

var mappedData = data.data.map(function(item){    
    var rand = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
    return { value: item[1], name: item[0], color: rand };
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that you are not creating `rand` for every item in `map`

Try this:

```
var mappedData = data.data.map(function(item) {
    var rand = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
    return {value: item[1], name: item[0], color: rand};
});
```